# How to upload only modified .cs file in WebServer in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webserver

I am using visual studio 2015, When I do changes on view page directly on the webserver, it is ok without any issues, because no need to be compiled the view page.

So how can I upload only modified **Controller** files on a webserver, instead of every time uploading all the files?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, the Controller code will get compiled into your projects DLL files.

If the reason that you're trying to do this is to save time publishing, you may want to look at CI/CD pipelines which could automate the entire process for you so you don't have to worry about it.

Cherry picking published files to upload to a server could cause issues anyway in my opinion and could be disastrous in a production environment.